# How can I decrease playback speed during editing in kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

I don't want to actually decrease the speed of any of the clips I'm working with. Rather, I want to slow the playback speed of the editor. (I'm attempting to insert images along with an audio clip in such a way that the images appear to the rhythm of the music. In some places, the rhythm to which I'd like to fit the images is quite fast.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: any answers for this?